# How to add user to exchange with using novell library

Tags: .net-core, active-directory, ldap, exchange-server, novell

help me to write a function in **c#.net core** that add user to **exchange** using **novell library** or any library that could do it .
the point is that I need run my code on linux.

Comment: You can't expect anyone to write your code for you. But if you search Google for ["create AD user c#"](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+AD+user+c%23) you will find answers. You can use `System.DirectoryServices` in .NET Core by using the [`Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) NuGet package - but then your project can only run on Windows (which may or may not be a problem)

Comment: thanks Gabriel, 
i tried write code that can add user to exchange and i don't success
then i search for create user to exchange, but i couldn't found answer.
I need a library that can work with exchange, 
I can't use System.DirectoryServices because I need to run my project on Linux and i need Add user to exchange, not to active directory

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word "exchange". I read it too fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about on premises Exchange (not Exchange Online, or Office 365).

You can't do this from Linux unfortunately.

Exchange does have a [web service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd877045(v%3Dexchg.140)), but it [cannot be used to create mailboxes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/29ada41f-3dd2-4a99-b63c-b78a87120651/ews-create-mailbox?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment).

The only way to create mailboxes in Exchange is to use PowerShell commands. This isn't terribly easy either. I have automated mailbox creation in C#, and I had to call the PowerShell commands from C# (and it has a ton of weird quirks - it's awful). But that, of course, can only be done on Windows.

Comment: actually i found powershell commands for this problem, but i couldn't use powershell, i must do with c#.net core and run on linux.

Comment: Right. That's why I said it cannot be done... You can only create a mailbox with PowerShell, but you can't run the PowerShell commands on Linux.